# ImageView Disappears when trying to Set the Width and Height programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget, imageview, layoutparams

Here is my code

```
onCreate()
{
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int w = size.x;
    int h = w * (9/16);
    img.getLayoutParams().height = h;
    img.getLayoutParams().width = w;
    img.requestLayout();

    //The rest of the code spawns a new thread and downloads an image for the image view.
}
```

and yeah I tried using the FrameLayout Params too (as my ImageView is in a FrameLayout), something like this img.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(w,h)), didn't work

Well what Im trying to do is **irrespective of the Image/Image SIZE** being downloaded, I want to create an ImageView with w:h = 16:9 ratio. What is the problem with my logic? I tried doing an img.requestLayout() too, didn't work, moved the code to onAttachWindow(), didn't work. Whats the problem here? Would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only problem with your code is this line:

```
 int h = w * (9/16);
```

The `(9/16)` is being performed as integer division, so it's resulting in `0`. Change it to:

```
 int h = (int)(w * 9f / 16f);
```

Comment: Ohhhhh shooot ! Why didnt I think of the int thing ! I will try this and let you know and I wonder whats wrong with the ImageView params in my code and why isnt that right. Really appreciate your help..!

Comment: yeah this works, but when I use Picasso to download the image, the imageview disappaears ....for example when doing something like this  Picasso.with(this).load(URL).fit().into(img, new Callback(){
   Override 
   public void onSuccess()
   {

   }
   Override
   public void onError()
   {
    //display error 
   }
  });

Comment: I got it right, but Picasso is not helping me out, so an AsyncTask finally helped me ....want to find out the reason though....

Comment: Damn Again Bro ! You know what Picasso actually seems to handle all kinds of security exceptions and prevent the app from Nasty crashes ! So in my case I didnt add the internet permission and VOILA ! It works...simple... and easy peasy ! But I have one more question for you..whats wronf with my code other than int part?